# Value from class is unreachable?

Tags: c#, windows-8

In my app I'm using a web request to pull json data from a web source and deserializing it into my class. I then want to pull a specific value from that data, but i'm finding that i can't reach with my current code.

Here are my classes

```
public class Result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int trackNumber { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> genres { get; set; }
    public Release release { get; set; }
    public Label label { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public int downloadId { get; set; }
    public string downloadUrl { get; set; } // value i'm trying to retrieve
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

and the code to deserialize the data then attempt to store the desired value into a string variable

```
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

string downloadUrl = data.results.downloadUrl; // downloadUrl is unreachable
```

Is there a better way to do this to get the value that I need? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results is a collection. Try that

```
string downloadUrl = data.results[0].downloadUrl;
```

It will give you downloadUrl from the first item from collection.